# How to add HTML tags functionality inside of a post model in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, sanitization, django-crispy-forms

I'm learning to build a blog post using django. The Blog post has a **title**, **introduction** and **body**. I want to be able to use HTML tags inside of the body field. I'm a newbie in programming and I don't know how to go about it. Please I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Write the HTML code in your body field like you would in a HTML file. Then, use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter to insert that HTML into the website. Beware of possible security issues.

```py
{{ body|safe|escape }}
```